# Launching external program Python with parameter

Tags: python

I need to launch a program within a python script that has an argument.
Code is:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import os
yesterday = (date.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%m%d%y')
os.system('"E:/Bootdrv/AlohaTs/Bin/grind.exe /yesterday"')
```

Any help?

Comment: ① What did you try? ② What did you expect to observe? ③ What did you observe instead?

Comment: What doesn't work with what you've got so far? Try to describe what you expect to happen, what you see happening, and post any error messages you get.

Comment: Maybe `os.system('E:/Bootdrv/AlohaTs/Bin/grind.exe /%s' % yesterday)` is what you want?

Comment: Try https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html.

Comment: @hspandher, I don't think OP is trying to parse arguments, they're trying to pass arguments to a different process.

Comment: I'm trying to pass argument to an external program that need yesterday as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

for calling a program with python i use subprocess lib

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

```
from subprocess import call
call("service camera restart")
```

this restart a linux service